# In playframework, where is the source code for `inputText` html helper?

Tags: scala, playframework, typesafe-activator, typesafe, twirl

I want to use the `inputText` method in html.helper for [forms](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaForms).

[Online Document for `inputText`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#views.html.helper.inputText$)

When I want to see how it generated the HTML code, I can't find its source code because the link to the source code embeded in their website is invalid: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/tree/2.3.x/framework/src/play/target/scala-2.10/twirl/main/views/html/helper/inputText.template.scala

Does anyone have ideas about where its source codes locate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the "src"-directory, not the "target":
https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/helper/inputText.scala.html